# When tapping an already selected cell in a UITableView, willSelectCellAtIndexPath gets called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with two sections.  Based on user interactions (selections and deselections), my datasource and `UITableView` are updated to move data between sections.  Initially their is only data in section 0. When I tap a cell, `willSelectCellAtIndexPath` and `didSelectCellAtIndexPath` get called.  As expected, when I tap the same cell again,  `didDeselectCellAtIndexPath` is called.

Even after I begin to move data down to section 1 and select and deselect, the `UITableView's` delegate methods are called appropriately.

Once all data has been moved to Section 1, the `UITableView` begins to exhibit strange behavior.  I can initially select a call and `didSelectCellAtIndexPath` is called.  However, when I tap it again, `didDeselectCellAtIndexPath` is never called.  Instead, any taps on the selected cell (I have confirmed it is indeed selected through `[tableView indexPathsForSelectedCells]` or any other cells in Section 1 only result in `willSelectIndexPath` and `didSelectIndexPath` getting called.

I have quite a bit of code in these delegate methods which is unrelated (I believe).... I do not explicitly change the selected state of a cell anywhere.  I have posted `willSelect` method and can post more if necessary.

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
if (remainingItemIsSelected && indexPath.section == 0) {
        //other cells in the remaining items section are selected and a cell from that section is being selected

        NSMutableIndexSet *arrayIndexesToBeDeleted = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init];
        for (NSIndexPath *previouslySelectedIndexPath in [tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows]) {
            if (((ReceiptItem *)[self.remainingReceiptItems objectAtIndex:previouslySelectedIndexPath.row]).allocated == YES) {

                //update data sources
                NSLog(@"%@%i%@,%i",@"Section #:",previouslySelectedIndexPath.section,@" Row #:",previouslySelectedIndexPath.row);
                [self.assignedReceiptItems addObject:[self.remainingReceiptItems objectAtIndex:previouslySelectedIndexPath.row]];
                [arrayIndexesToBeDeleted addIndex:previouslySelectedIndexPath.row];

                //update index path arrays
                [self.receiptItemsToDeleteIndexPaths addObject:previouslySelectedIndexPath];
                [self.receiptItemsToAddIndexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.assignedReceiptItems.count-1 inSection:1]];

                //update the pressed indexpath to equal to resulting indexpath to pass on to the didSelect method
                if (previouslySelectedIndexPath.row < indexPath.row) {
                    indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row-1 inSection:0];
                }
            }
        }
        //Delete assigned items from the remaining receipt items
        [self.remainingReceiptItems removeObjectsAtIndexes:arrayIndexesToBeDeleted];
        //update table (move allocated item down)
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:self.receiptItemsToDeleteIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:self.receiptItemsToAddIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        [tableView endUpdates];
        if (self.remainingReceiptItems.count == 0) {
            [tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        }
        //other cells in the remaining items section are selected and a cell from assigned items is being selected
        return nil;
    }
    return indexPath;
}
```

Comment: Did you set breakpoints to check if the method is called? Or are you considering only your `NSLog()` statements?

Comment: I set breakpoints and confirmed that `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` is not called.  Additionally, I confirmed that `willDeselectRowAtIndexPath` is not called either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Documentation for UITableViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html):

> **tableView:willDeselectRowAtIndexPath:**
>   This method is only called if there is an existing selection when the user tries to select a different row. The delegate is sent this method for the previously selected row.

If you think this through you will find that what you encounter is expected behavior. Tapping a row that is selected does **not** call `will/didDeselctRowAtIndexPath` on this row.

Instead, you could handle this in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` for the selected row, i.e. deselect it there.

***Possible Alternative***

That being said, I think you are abusing the `UITableView` class. It is really not designed to do this moving stuff. You have no doubt noticed yourself that you have to write a lot of code to make this work -- the very reason you are encountering intractable errors.

It seems to me that a much cleaner (and ultimately more flexible) solution would be to have two separate table (or other) views that notify each other via delegates about `datasource` changes. Maybe a bit more work setting it up, but surely much less trouble down the road.

Comment: Thanks.  Interesting because if you have `allowsMultipleSelection` set to YES then the above documentation does not hold (a tap on a selected cell) calls `will/didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`.  I want to do this as clean/flexible as possible but I do not see how separate table views would solve that.  In the tableview delegate methods, instead of having conditionals for the `section` value wouldn't I now need conditionals to determine which `UITableView` is making the call?  Do I need to set the datasource and delegate for each one different than the ViewController's .m file they are contained in?

Comment: The cleanest way without having to deal with a single datasource for more than one table view (which is possible - see eg. Apple's code for search results controllers) is to have one controller that controls two table view controllers.